# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/react/uimanager/UIImplementationProvider;

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing while opening my android app. I tried with below steps but I am getting this below error. Kindly help me. my Android app builds fine but when I run it I get the below error. It references a class which is not something that I use.  Any ideas?

```
com.qa.android E/unknown:NativeModuleInitError: Failed to create NativeModule "UIManager"
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/react/uimanager/UIImplementationProvider;
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.createUIManager(ReanimatedPackage.java:73)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.getModule(ReanimatedPackage.java:31)
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:161)
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:149)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.create(ModuleHolder.java:191)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule(ModuleHolder.java:156)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.getModule(NativeModuleRegistry.java:170)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:493)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:469)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:89)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:47)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1241)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1183)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1600(ReactInstanceManager.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1137)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementationProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~7b9OfUY0mLPaHfZSYMHhqQ==/com.qa.android-4UNR7KbO89A4FSaahSgIvw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~7b9OfUY0mLPaHfZSYMHhqQ==/com.qa.android-4UNR7KbO89A4FSaahSgIvw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~7b9OfUY0mLPaHfZSYMHhqQ==/com.qa.android-4UNR7KbO89A4FSaahSgIvw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.createUIManager(ReanimatedPackage.java:73) 
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.getModule(ReanimatedPackage.java:31) 
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:161) 
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:149) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.create(ModuleHolder.java:191) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule(ModuleHolder.java:156) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.getModule(NativeModuleRegistry.java:170) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:493) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:469) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:89) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:47) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1241) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1183) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1600(ReactInstanceManager.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1137) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2022-11-06 01:30:47.279 20077-20173/com.qa.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.qa.android, PID: 20077
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/react/uimanager/UIImplementationProvider;
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.createUIManager(ReanimatedPackage.java:73)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.getModule(ReanimatedPackage.java:31)
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:161)
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:149)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.create(ModuleHolder.java:191)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule(ModuleHolder.java:156)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.getModule(NativeModuleRegistry.java:170)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:493)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:469)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:89)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:47)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1241)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1183)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1600(ReactInstanceManager.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1137)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementationProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~7b9OfUY0mLPaHfZSYMHhqQ==/com.qa.android-4UNR7KbO89A4FSaahSgIvw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~7b9OfUY0mLPaHfZSYMHhqQ==/com.qa.android-4UNR7KbO89A4FSaahSgIvw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~7b9OfUY0mLPaHfZSYMHhqQ==/com.qa.android-4UNR7KbO89A4FSaahSgIvw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.createUIManager(ReanimatedPackage.java:73) 
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.getModule(ReanimatedPackage.java:31) 
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:161) 
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:149) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.create(ModuleHolder.java:191) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule(ModuleHolder.java:156) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.getModule(NativeModuleRegistry.java:170) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:493) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:469) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:89) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:47) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1241) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1183) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1600(ReactInstanceManager.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1137) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I implemented in this below way

```
 if (enableHermes) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
                 }
//        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
//        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
//        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
```

I am getting crash on startup . Please kindly help me,.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Build Failure: Common Issue- Failed to install the app. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thanhal. But not fixed it

Comment: Oh ok I have checked for another solutions and found that if you are using react-native-navigation then upgrade it to latest version and try

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue trending last 2 days.

add this into your `android/buld.gradle` inside `allprojects`

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

I followed this comment https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35204#issuecomment-1304281740 and it works fine now.

Comment: This one not fixed in my case.

Comment: This was correct at the time of posting, but since then, Facebook has released updates to current and older versions of React Native. [Facebook's updates](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

Comment: omg thank you man, you made my week, I was pulling hair of my head

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of [Ammar's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334272/1897885) ,

In case anyone is looking for a solution within Gradle (without using command line & node. Might be helpful to avoid certain CI/CD restrictions)

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = {
  def inputFile = new File("$rootDir/../package.json")
  def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)

  return packageJson["dependencies"]["react-native"]
}()

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
      }
    }
}
```

You will have to change `package.json` path based on your file structure.

[Official issue here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

Comment: Where did you get JsonSlurper from?

Comment: use this library import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

Answer (score 0):

Every second person is facing this issue even I too I resolved by adding these codes in app/build.gradle

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim());
                configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Facebook has provided instructions to resolve this issue. The workaround mentioned in previous answers is no longer recommended. Please refer to this article for guidance.
[Facebook's solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)