# Suddenly facing this issue. Previously it was working fine

Tags: reactjs, react-native

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Peace Garden'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0 was found. The consumer was configured
> to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally,
> as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.3.3'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Build Failure: Common Issue- Failed to install the app. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f)

Comment: I have added those lines into my app.gradle file but still facing the same.

Comment: Try this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370367/my-react-native-was-working-fine-upto-4-november-but-now-throwing-an-exception-w