# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction (React-Native)

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing an error in my react-native app. It was working fine till the last day. But I am getting this error suddenly.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\UseR\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\6155e8579eef6966fa5e497cf95302d3\transformed\jetified-react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug\jni
      - C:\Users\UseR\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ed012637c43cfa225ec67c43b7549cf1\transformed\jetified-fbjni-0.3.0\jni
     If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s

    at makeError (D:\cloudtaru\mobile_app\mobile_app\Admin\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at D:\cloudtaru\mobile_app\mobile_app\Admin\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (D:\cloudtaru\mobile_app\mobile_app\Admin\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (D:\cloudtaru\mobile_app\mobile_app\Admin\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Build Failure: Common Issue- Failed to install the app. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f)