# I get Task :app:processDebugMainManifest error in react native how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native project it was implemented untill 2 days ago but after that it didnt. I get this error ( Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exporte) bfore this error I got error compileSdkVersion to 31 and I changed it from 30 to 31 but I get the abow error.  it was runed but now why doesn't?

AndroidManifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.mazeapp">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"
      tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />


  <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground (remote-only, for local use ignoreInForeground) -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="false" />
    <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@color/white" /> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mazeapp.ir" android:pathPrefix="/app" />
        <data android:scheme="maze" android:host="payment" android:pathPrefix="/verify" />
        <data android:scheme="taraz" android:host="timer" android:pathPrefix="/link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="tarazapp.com" android:pathPrefix="/app" />
        <data android:scheme="taraz" android:host="payment" android:pathPrefix="/verify" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    <service android:name="com.asterinet.react.bgactions.RNBackgroundActionsTask" />

  </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        // googlePlayServicesVersion = "4.3.3" // default: "+"
        // firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        kotlinVersion = '1.5.0'
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  
      }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mazeapp",
  "version": "2.2.8",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "4.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.12",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "3.5.0",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "4.0.4",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "1.4.2",
    "react-native-background-actions": "^2.6.4",
    "react-native-background-timer": "2.4.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.2.0",
    "react-native-copilot": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "5.6.5",
    "react-native-emoji": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-file-picker": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.5.6",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "2.3.4",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-item-select": "0.3.0",
    "react-native-modal": "11.5.6",
    "react-native-modalbox": "2.0.2",
    "react-native-motion": "1.0.5",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-persian-calendar-picker": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-progress": "4.1.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-ratings": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-select-contact": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-simple-modal": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "0.11.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "5.4.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-typing-animation": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-uuid-generator": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.10.1",
    "react-number-format": "4.4.1",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "victory-native": "^33.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.16.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.16.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-native-bundle-visualizer": "2.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Build Failure: Common Issue- Failed to install the app. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f)

Comment: I add configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
    } in build.gradle , and it works fine but what does it do?

Comment: It's a common issue in Android due to the publish of the React Native version 0.71.0-rc0 - Reason and all mentioned here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210