# Issue with React Native - Async Storage

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run my react-native app but suddenly receiving the following error:

```
Task :react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

My project was fine till Friday (05th November). I am getting this from today morning.

```
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.7.1",

buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip
```

Comment: It's common issue. Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f

Comment: @Thanhal that build error resolved, thanks to you. But now I am getting a new one regarding kotlin version in 'react-native-screens'.
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'. A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction