# Android build failed after updating react native version to 0.70

Tags: android, react-native

I have tried to update our react native app from 0.67 to 0.70 with this guide:
[text](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.67.2&to=0.70.4)
and wasnt able to build android even after returnung to my main branch with out any changes.
I am keep getting the error.
"cannot choose between the following variants of com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.04"

I was tring to update my react native app and expected to be able to build android successfully after the update.

Comment: I found the solution to this problem, you can read about it in the following:
[link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f