# while taking a build in android studio (react native)

Tags: react-native, kotlin, apk

```
    Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the
```

2 files found with path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'.
If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets

changes in build.gradle file

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f