# Issue with react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin

Tags: react-native

I am getting the below error:

```
> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I already tried this [one](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/1369#issuecomment-1105152720), didn't work.

```
"react-native": "0.61.5"
"react-native-screens": "^3.18.2"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f

Comment: No. I have already applied Method 2, but didn't work. @Thanhal

Comment: Oh okay just commented since these issues were coming past two days