# bare React Native build failed after installing expo package

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I was building bare React Native app  but build failed after installing expo and expo modules package with :

```
 npx install-expo-modules@latest
```

build errors after running `npm run android`

```
The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core'

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
147 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 144 up-to-date
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainActivity.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;
^
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainApplication.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;
^
2 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainActivity.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;
^
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainApplication.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;
^
2 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s

    at makeError (C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
npm verb exit 1
npm verb code 1
```

changes: [changes before latest commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mm8O.png)

`android/settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'instagram'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle")
useExpoModules()
```

`android/build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper;
package com.instagram;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "instagram";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
   * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
   * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED, new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled(), // fabricEnabled
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent React (i.e. React 18).
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getConcurrentReactEnabled() // concurrentRootEnabled
        ));
  }
}
```

`MainApplication.java`

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;
package com.instagram;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebooak.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      });

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }
}
```

it's only been 3 weeks since started react-native and spend 3 days on this bug.
please tell me if i should include anything else too, thanks

I tried:

1. delating node_modules and installing again
2. cleaning and rebuilding ./gradlew
3. deleting and rebuilding .gradle file
4. I tried adding:

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
   
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
          force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
      }
  }
 // other code
}
```

to `android/build.gradle`

based on solution from this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346206/task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-failed)

5. i added kotlin plugin to root `build.gradle` file `classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10')`

new error:

```
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
214 actionable tasks: 208 executed, 6 up-to-date
Note: C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\react-native-image-picker\android\src\main\java\com\imagepicker\Utils.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\react-native-video\android\src\main\java\com\brentvatne\react\ReactVideoViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainActivity.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;
^
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainApplication.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;
^
2 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\react-native-image-picker\android\src\main\java\com\imagepicker\Utils.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\react-native-video\android\src\main\java\com\brentvatne\react\ReactVideoViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainActivity.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;
^
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainApplication.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;
^
2 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 2s

    at makeError (C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Nothing worked

*os: Windows*

Comment: ```The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.``` This could be a hint

Comment: @esQmo_ but where should it be modified?  and how can I trace it? I'm using standart react-native template

Comment: I never used React-native, but the log shows interresting infos. Such as ```The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core'```

Comment: Do you have a development environment setup for Android? : ```error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\matea\Desktop\react-native\projects\instagram\android\app\src\main\java\com\instagram\MainActivity.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.instagram;```

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: yes I have, it was working fine before i installed expo modules and it caused some conflicts. if I revert back it still works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, in the MainActivity.java file, it's package `com.YourAppName;` was not in the first line.
After putting this line above everything, the problem was fixed

**Before:**

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
package com.YourAppName;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;
```

**After:**

```
package com.YourAppName;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;
```

For the expo-camera implementation, it was also nessesary to add `implementation("com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0")` inside the `android/app/build.gradle` file