# Adding Firebase to my React Native app breaks it

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I am trying to integrate Firebase into my React Native (cli) app, but after I do, I can't build my app anymore and it keeps failing.

I've tried to integrate it into an existing app, but figured I want to try to isolate the problem because it was getting too messy, so I've created a brand new project (npx react-native@latest init cli).

Assume my desired package name is `codes.johnny.checkers`.
My react-native version is `0.72.4`

After creating the project I've done the following.

I've created an Android project in Firebase, with `codes.johnny.checkers` setup as my package name.
I've read in the documentation that it should match what's in the manifest tag in `android/appsrc/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

My manifest tag looked like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

So I've changed it to this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="codes.johnny.checkers">
```

Next, I've downloaded the `google-services.json` file provided by firebase, and placed it in `android/app/src/google-services.json`.

Now to integration.
First I've installed `@react-native-firebase/app` as a dependancy.

Then, in `android/build.gradle` I've added:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

under `dependencies`.

Then, in `android/app/build.gradle` I've added:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

At the top (last after the other two `apply plugin` statements that were there).

At this point, the integration instructions at https://rnfirebase.io/ basically end, so I tried to run the app with `npx react-native run-android`. It fails an this is what I see.

```
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 32.2.3
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 20.6.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 18.4.0 (18,4,0 - 18004000)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\react-native\android

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
12 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.cli'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
error Failed to install the app.
```

While it doesn't say so in the docs, the fail error does, so in `android/app/build.gradle` I've changed namespace to `codes.johnny.checkers` and also `defaulConfig/applicationId` to `codes.johnny.checkers`.

I've tried to run the app again, and now this is what I get:

```
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 32.2.3
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 20.6.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 18.4.0 (18,4,0 - 18004000)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\react-native\android

> Task :react-native-firebase_app:processDebugManifest
package="io.invertase.firebase" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
package="codes.johnny.checkers" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
50 actionable tasks: 41 executed, 9 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\android\app\src\main\java\com\cli\MainApplication.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
                 ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\android\app\src\main\java\com\cli\MainApplication.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
                 ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\android\app\src\main\java\com\cli\MainApplication.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
                 ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\android\app\src\main\java\com\cli\MainApplication.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
        ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainApplication
C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\android\app\src\main\java\com\cli\MainApplication.java:56: error: illegal parenthesized expression
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
       ^
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 27s
error Failed to install the app.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

With this line being bright red, I guess pointing to it being the main error/issue:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

I've just noticed the following was printed:

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
package="codes.johnny.checkers" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.
```

So I removed it from the manifest as I have manually added it. Didn't effect anything though, app still doesn't work.

I've tried the recommendation here as well but to no avail.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74346417/9774624

The recommendation was adding the following to `android/build.gradle`

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


buildscript {
     // ...
}
    
    
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
    }
    // ...  
}
```

EDIT 2:

I've tried adding the following to he bottom of my `android/build.gradle` but also fails:

```
buildscript {
     // ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories{
        exclusiveContent{
            filter{
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven{
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The fail log here was a little different though:

```
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 32.2.3
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 20.6.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 18.4.0 (18,4,0 - 18004000)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\thinkin\cli\node_modules\react-native\android
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.4.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.72.4.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.4.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-firebase_app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
error Failed to install the app.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```