# Task :react-native-callkeep:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, compiler-errors

I leave the error. I was working with this module until yesterday. Whn I try to run appear this error. If I create a new project when install it, Appear always the same
`

```
                                                           ^
```

F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:70: error: package androidx.core.app
does not exist
import static androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:70: error: static import only from cl
asses and interfaces
import static androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
public class RNCallKeepModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
^
symbol: class ReactContextBaseJavaModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
private static Promise hasPhoneAccountPromise;
^
symbol:   class Promise
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
private ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
^
symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
private ReadableMap _settings;
^
symbol:   class ReadableMap
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
public RNCallKeepModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
^
symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
public void setup(ReadableMap options) {
^
symbol:   class ReadableMap
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:219: error: cannot find symbol
public void checkPhoneAccountPermission(ReadableArray optionalPermissions, Promise promise) {
^
symbol:   class ReadableArray
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:219: error: cannot find symbol
public void checkPhoneAccountPermission(ReadableArray optionalPermissions, Promise promise) {
^
symbol:   class Promise
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:249: error: cannot find symbol
public void checkDefaultPhoneAccount(Promise promise) {
^
symbol:   class Promise
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:348: error: cannot find symbol
public void hasPhoneAccount(Promise promise) {
^
symbol:   class Promise
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:353: error: cannot find symbol
public void hasOutgoingCall(Promise promise) {
^
symbol:   class Promise
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:358: error: cannot find symbol
public void hasPermissions(Promise promise) {
^
symbol:   class Promise
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:469: error: cannot find symbol
private void sendEventToJS(String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
^
symbol:   class WritableMap
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:20: error: package com.facebook.reac
t does not exist
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:21: error: package com.facebook.reac
t.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:22: error: package com.facebook.reac
t.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:23: error: package com.facebook.reac
t.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:24: error: package com.facebook.reac
t.uimanager does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
public class RNCallKeepPackage implements ReactPackage {
^
symbol: class ReactPackage
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
public List createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
^
symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
location: class RNCallKeepPackage
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
public List createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
^
symbol:   class NativeModule
location: class RNCallKeepPackage
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
^
symbol:   class JavaScriptModule
location: class RNCallKeepPackage
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
public List createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
^
symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
location: class RNCallKeepPackage
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
public List createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
^
symbol:   class ViewManager
location: class RNCallKeepPackage
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\VoiceConnection.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
^
symbol:   class Nullable
location: package androidx.annotation
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\VoiceConnection.java:27: error: package androidx.localbroad
castmanager.content does not exist
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\VoiceConnectionService.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
^
symbol:   class Nullable
location: package androidx.annotation
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\VoiceConnectionService.java:30: error: package androidx.loc
albroadcastmanager.content does not exist
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService.java:37: error: cannot
find symbol
protected @Nullable
^
symbol:   class Nullable
location: class RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:150: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:164: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:186: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:202: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:218: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:248: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:266: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:293: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:307: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:326: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:336: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:347: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:352: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:357: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:362: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:367: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:372: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:383: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:402: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:413: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:419: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactMethod
^
symbol:   class ReactMethod
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:469: error: cannot find symbol
private void sendEventToJS(String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
^
symbol:   class Nullable
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\VoiceConnection.java:202: error: cannot find symbol
private void sendCallRequestToActivity(final String action, @Nullable final HashMap attributeMap) {
^
symbol:   class Nullable
location: class VoiceConnection
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\VoiceConnectionService.java:273: error: cannot find symbol
private void sendCallRequestToActivity(final String action, @Nullable final HashMap attributeMap) {
^
symbol:   class Nullable
location: class VoiceConnectionService
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService.java:36: error: method
does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService.java:41: error: cannot
find symbol
return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
^
symbol:   class HeadlessJsTaskConfig
location: class RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService.java:43: error: cannot
find symbol
Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
^
symbol:   variable Arguments
location: class RNCallKeepBackgroundMessagingService
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:113: error: method does not override
or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:220: error: cannot find symbol
Activity currentActivity = this.getCurrentActivity();
^
symbol: method getCurrentActivity()
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:241: error: cannot find symbol
requestPermissions(currentActivity, allPermissions, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
^
symbol:   method requestPermissions(Activity,String[],int)
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:424: error: cannot find symbol
Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
^
symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:438: error: cannot find symbol
getReactApplicationContext().startActivity(focusIntent);
^
symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:470: error: cannot find symbol
this.reactContext.getJSModule(RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName, params);
^
symbol:   class RCTDeviceEventEmitter
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:481: error: cannot find symbol
Activity currentActivity = this.getCurrentActivity();
^
symbol: method getCurrentActivity()
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:485: error: cannot find symbol
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(currentActivity, permission);
^
symbol:   variable ContextCompat
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:511: error: cannot find symbol
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.reactContext).registerReceiver(voiceBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
^
symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
location: class RNCallKeepModule
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:536: error: cannot find symbol
WritableMap args = Arguments.createMap();
^
symbol:   class WritableMap
location: class RNCallKeepModule.VoiceBroadcastReceiver
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:536: error: cannot find symbol
WritableMap args = Arguments.createMap();
^
symbol:   variable Arguments
location: class RNCallKeepModule.VoiceBroadcastReceiver
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepModule.java:594: error: cannot find symbol
HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(reactContext);
^
symbol:   variable HeadlessJsTaskService
location: class RNCallKeepModule.VoiceBroadcastReceiver
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:31: error: method does not override
or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
return Collections.singletonList(new RNCallKeepModule(reactContext));
^
symbol:   class NativeModule
location: class RNCallKeepPackage
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\RNCallKeepPackage.java:41: error: method does not override
or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native-callkeep\android\src\main\java\io\wazo\callkeep\VoiceConnection.java:215: error: cannot find symbol
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
^
symbol: variable LocalBroadcastManager
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
100 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-callkeep:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s

```
at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:828:11)
at execFileSync (node:child_process:863:15)
at runOnAllDevices (F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Command.handleAction (F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
```

```
`

I have tried all this solutions below:

change the implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+' to 19.8.0
add the onRewardedVideoCompleted() method in RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule
update the compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion in RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule
set the enableJetifier to false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f

Comment: No, it doesn't. @Thanhal

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? I am experiencing the same problem...

Comment: @Mark yes bro. I have mentioned the answer below, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they will update the package, but to solve this issue by yourself, go to react-native-callkeep-hk/android/build.gradle and add follow line on dependencies:
implementation "androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0"

Comment: It worked but just for this issue. Now the issue is changed and is shifted to another class in Node Modules which is following :-
F:\lantis_new_and_updated\node_modules\@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java:270: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: Try reinstall the AsyncStorage. After that, go to android folder by terminal and run ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew --stop and try to run again

Answer (score 0):

**This solution has worked for me**
In android level **build.gradle** file:

```
 def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '-- 
 print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react- 
 native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, 
 rootDir).text.trim())
 buildscript {
 // ...
 }
 allprojects {
 configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
      }
 }
 // ...  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Running these command works for me.**

- npm install --save-dev jetifier
- npx jetify
- npx react-native run-android

you can check out https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier#to-jetify--convert-node_modules-dependencies-to-androidx for details.