# Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac' while trying to build Android App

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, urbanairship.com, react-native-device-info

Anyone can please help me with resolving the below error. I am getting this issue while building android app with in React Native project.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-fast-image:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':urbanairship-react-native:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Build Failure: Common Issue- Failed to install the app. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f)