# Your React Native app not build without doing any changes? Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' androidx-appcompatappcompat1.4.X

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native app not built without doing any changes!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Build Failure: Common Issue- Failed to install the app. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> Do these changes

1. android\build.gradle under allproject->repositories Just before
   maven

> Add this

```
exclusiveContent {
   filter {
       includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
   }
   forRepository {
       maven {         
          url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
       }
   }
}
```