# Build Failed: error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gitlab, yarnpkg, package.json

I clonend the app from gitlab with my access tokens. It wokrs, but when I try to run the app from run:android:dev it gives me this long failed message.
I tried to delete node_modules then I reinstalled  yarn, but I still get the same error.

Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

I tried to run the app as dev (run:android:dev), but after 52% of progress it fails.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Build Failure: Common Issue- Failed to install the app. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f)

Comment: Please always share code and error messages as text. Here you can find good reasons why: [ask]