# Error when trying to build a React Native application with EAS

Tags: react-native, expo, mapbox, eas

I'm trying to build a React Native application using Expo and [rnmapbox/maps](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps) module, which includes some custom native code.

Up until now, I could build the application without any problems, for Android at least, which is my target platform. But suddenly, it stopped working and the following error log is displayed:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin'.
   > Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_1quotit9ccucu377qnhf7kv5h$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure5@4a87f9f7] on configuration ':app:archives' of type org.gradle.api.in
ternal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.
```

What is the problem and how can I possibly fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `"image": "latest"` field to `eas.json` configuration and it seemed to fix the problem.

Apparently, there was a bug with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with Mapbox. We are experiencing the same error as you on our Android builds under `eas build`. We just removed the rnmapbox/maps dependency and commented out all the relevant code and our builds are passing.