# App is being crashed instantly after build : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libturbomodulejsijni.so

Tags: android, react-native

I was using RN V0.63.3 until [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210) build failures happenings.
I change my version to 0.63.5 and build done successfully. **Now my application is being crashed instantly after build in development mode.**

ERROR log :

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libturbomodulejsijni.so
SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/user/0/com.zcarpet/lib-main flags = 1]
SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = ...

I upgraded my gradle version from 3.5.2 to 3.5.3 and tried these fixes :

1. I used this code in \Android\build.gradle :

```
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.5" 
        }
    }
```

2. Add below code in \Android\build.gridle :

```
    project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
        deleteDebugFilesForVariant: { false }
    ]
```

3. many other fixes that could not help...

my project configurations :

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        if (useIntlJsc) {
            implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
        } else {
            implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
        }
    }
    }

    allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.5" 
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        maven { url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com' }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
    // Workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/117900475
    // Remove when upgrading to AGP 3.4 or higher.
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            details.useVersion("3.5.0-alpha03-5252756")
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please follow below steps and check

1. Revert back all the changes you have made after that (downgrade gradle, react-native, java & everything as like before)
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Delete build folders (`android/build` & `android/app/build`)
4. Recheck the `package.json` if the `react-native` version is as which was worked before (in your case `0.63.3`)
5. Run `npm install` or `yarn` to install packages
6. Clean (remove gradle cache like mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/10657559) and rebuild the app by adding the below changes to your `android/build.gradle` file

```html
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


buildscript {
     // ...
}
    
    
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
    }
    // ...  
}
```

Ref: [Fix and updates on Android build failures happening since Nov 4th 2022 #35210](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

Comment: How to delete android/build ?
by rm -rf android/build?

Comment: There is no build file but build.gradle do I need to delete that one?

Comment: it's ok if there is no build file(it mean build is already clean). Don't delete gradle files just follow remaining steps mentioned above

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I did every things carefully, but app still crashes instantly after build.

Comment: I think it's because of `implementation jscFlavor`, when I enable hermes, error changes to realm "hermes supporting errors".

Answer (score 1):

Finally I restored my November first backup, just added below code and it worked.

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


buildscript {
     // ...
}
    
    
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
    }
    // ...  
}
```

Comment: Adding the above to build.gradle also fixed for me. RN 0.64.0