# React Native Task :react-native-image-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio, gradle, react-native-image-picker

When trying to run my project on my windows computer it is not working, it works on my macOS but when running it on windows it throws the following errors:

```
Task :react-native-image-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
  location: class VERSION_CODES
```

Running it with `npx react-native run-android`

`build.gradle` has the following:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 30
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
                ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```

Have been trying to change the number with everything I have installed, `29`,`30`,`31`,and `33` minSdk, buildTools, compile, and targeted nothing is working.

Currently, have node 14 and JDK 11

Error changes when I use 33 to the following one:

```
 Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

Have already tried multiple times `./gradlew clean`

Someone knows what's going on? what am I missing?

Comment: What is your RN Version you are currently using?

Comment: Refer to this GitHub Issue here, there was a global android build issue in react native when they released `0.70.0-rc0`. Read https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210 to know what action you have to take regarding it.

Comment: `^0.64.1` That's the react native version im currently using

Comment: Consider Upgrading to `RN 0.64.4` and test if that solves your issue.

Comment: tried upgrading to several new ones, different packages differnt errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I downgrade version of react-native-image-picker to 0.38.1, works for me

Comment: Maybe you talked about react-native-image-crop-picker

Comment: i'm getting this error npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for react-native-image-picker@0.38.1

Answer (score 3):

Just change the version of your image picker to

```
"react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
```

in Package.Json and then

Delete Node Modules and then Run npm i --force after that cd android and then ./gradlew clean

Works well for me !

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade might work but you can also try to upgrade to the latest version. In my case, apparently, npm installed version 4.10.3 when the latest version is 5.3.1. just write:

```
npm install react-native-image-picker@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if both mac & windows have same java version by running
   command `java -version`
2. If no, change the version of java in windows like as in mac then, clean and rebuild
3. If yes, check if one of this this solution works :

   - [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)
   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74371195/10657559

Comment: tried everything here and nothing worked :(

Answer (score -2):

In my app, the error was fixed by fixing the version of the library in this way: 'react-native-image-picker': '4.6.0', removing the ^ from 'react-native-image-picker': '^4.6.0'. After that, run yarn install or npm install

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).