# Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED aftrer gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, release

I create react-native ,I try to release apk to android
by this commit `gradlew assembleRelease` but I have this error :

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED e: D:\Abd
> El-Rahman\TijaryStockApp\TijaryStockApp\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\tasks\BundleHermesCTask.kt: (137, 11): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be
> marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or
> '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'

in my environment I added
this:
[image]

And this:
[image]

and add this in PATH:
[image]

Can any one help Me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)

Comment: No, I have method 2 in my code

Comment: Try if this works : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74372862/10657559

Comment: Yes I try It,but no thing happen