# app is not building recently it working properly but as i add other package it stop

Tags: react-native

[image: this is the issue]

[image: this is my jason]
**app is not building recently it working properly but as I add other package it stop **

Comment: Also please post your error logs in reproducible(text) format and not as images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

I had the same issue yesterday. The issue is not related to any new library installation directly although I had the same assumption initially.

Upgrade react-native version to the relevant patch number mentioned in the Github issue which I believe in your case it would be 0.70.5