# Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseRFile FAILED

Tags: react-native

i got a bug when i build react native apk. last week I built no error. but now an error occurs, even though there is no new package that I installed.

```
Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseRFile FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=release, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar
```

i wish i could build apk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hope this can help you [[FIXED] Android build failures No matching variant of com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0 was found](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was because of using maven's react native version how I fixed it.
android/build.gradle

```
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    exclusiveContent {
       filter {
           includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
       }
       forRepository {
           maven {
               url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
           }
       }
   }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    }

    mavenCentral {
        // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central 
        as there are
        // older versions over there.
        content {
            excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
        }
    }
    google()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `allprojects` area of your `android/buld.gradle` file.

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations. All {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
```

> direct solution from accepted answer worked form me

[Android build failures No matching variant of com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0 was found.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)