# Android build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, eas

this is what the ide showing on building - Android build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information., and when opening in expo, the below error message was found. can anybody plaese solve this ?

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
[stderr] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
[stderr]    > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/release/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1cb34187.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@65ffa193.). Check logs for more details.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 3m 2s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
146 actionable tasks: 146 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)