# Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED issue due to rg.wonday.orientation.OrientationPackage

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am facing the following issue while running command : 'react-native run-android' , I have tried to make changes in '/Users/ankitkumar/teachersapp_new/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java' but it automatically get reset when running the command. Can anyone please help?

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
665 actionable tasks: 77 executed, 588 up-to-date
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
/Users/ankitkumar/teachersapp_new/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:63: error: a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of OrientationPackage
import org.wonday.orientation.OrientationPackage;
^
/Users/ankitkumar/teachersapp_new/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:158: error: reference to OrientationPackage is ambiguous
      new OrientationPackage(),
          ^
  both class com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage in com.github.yamill.orientation and class org.wonday.orientation.OrientationPackage in org.wonday.orientation match
/Users/ankitkumar/teachersapp_new/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:159: error: reference to OrientationPackage is ambiguous
      new OrientationPackage(),
          ^
  both class com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage in com.github.yamill.orientation and class org.wonday.orientation.OrientationPackage in org.wonday.orientation match
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
/Users/ankitkumar/teachersapp_new/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:63: error: a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of OrientationPackage
import org.wonday.orientation.OrientationPackage;
^
/Users/ankitkumar/teachersapp_new/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:158: error: reference to OrientationPackage is ambiguous
      new OrientationPackage(),
          ^
  both class com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage in com.github.yamill.orientation and class org.wonday.orientation.OrientationPackage in org.wonday.orientation match
/Users/ankitkumar/teachersapp_new/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:159: error: reference to OrientationPackage is ambiguous
      new OrientationPackage(),
          ^
  both class com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage in com.github.yamill.orientation and class org.wonday.orientation.OrientationPackage in org.wonday.orientation match
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
```

I have tried to make changes in '/Users/ankitkumar/teachersapp_new/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java' but it automatically get reset when running the command and the build is unsuccessful.

Comment: It is for react-native 0.71, I have react-native 0.68.0

Comment: Still getting the same issue

Comment: Yes, I reverted every change and cleaned

Comment: Yes react-native-orientation 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps and check if same issue still exist

1. If you did any [manual linking](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#manual-linking) like mentioned here then revert back all the changes
2. Run `npx react-native unlink react-native-orientation`
3. Run `npm uninstall react-native-orientation`
4. Delete `node_modules`
5. Delete build folders (`android/build` & `android/app/build`)
6. Run `npm install` or `yarn` to install packages
7. Check if app builds without `react-native-orientation` package.If yes, goto next next. If no, add the fix mentioned here [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in) then check if app works then, execute next step
8. run `npm install react-native-orientation`
9. Run `npx react-native link react-native-orientation`
10. Clean & build

Comment: My issue is resolved by keeping one of react-native-orientation or react-native-orientation-lock

Comment: oh so you downloaded both. that's why this error: a type with the same simple **name is already** defined by the single-type-import of OrientationPackage. I thought you did both manual & auto linking which could be also the reason. Anyway good