# How to fix gradle build failed with unknown error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I build my app with `expo` after running `eas build` I keep getting this same error
`Android build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information."`

this is the log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zI4UdV2XSpDooz_UuoDkWL8ODoe37SHQ/view?usp=share_link

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.6.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I will appreciate your help, this is already frustrating me for the past 3 day now, I cant process to the next stage.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)

Comment: I have tried, delete my `node_modules` do the `npm install` back I still get the same error.

Comment: i am stuck at this from past 2 days, not able to push updates. please help if you solved this.