# android Build is failing giving this error : Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-firebase

[image: android Build is failing giving this error]

I  tried - reset cache files , invalidate caches, wipe data in android studio , reset bundler cache.

Comment: Are you trying to run an existing project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add code as code (text), not as an image, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask