# react native: Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

Tags: react-native

android studio v4.1.3
react native v0.63.4

once I run react native project, it throws this error
I've tried to upgrade minSdk version to 21 as it mentioned in the suggestion, but it doesn't work.

[image: image shows the error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)