# > Task :react-native-camera:generateGeneralDebugRFile FAILED. How to resolve this?

Tags: android, react-native, simulator, android-build

I have added all the configuration as per the docs said. But this error is showing now. What to do?

the app should install on simulator on android without error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

*Insert the following lines in android/build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 16
      compileSdkVersion = 28
      targetSdkVersion = 28
      supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
      googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0" // Insert or set latest version 
      androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
}


android {
  ...
  default config {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' // <--- insert this line
  }
}
```

https://react-native-camera.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/installation