# minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0]

Tags: android, react-native

Following is my `React-Native` app's configuration,

**android/app/buid.gradle:**

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    multiDexEnabled true
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
```

Facing following error when I run from `Android Studio`

> minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0]

I must support `minSdkVersion 19` as many of my users are still using lower versions of android.

Hence, How can i continue with `minSdkVersion 19` with out any error?

Note: I have gone through the suggested question and have already applied suggested changes. But still facing the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)